# Workaround to linker script "INSERT BEFORE" with GNU gold

Tags: gnu, sections, linker-scripts, gold-linker

I have a linker script that currently works with GNU ld.
I wanted to link using GNU gold but I am hitting an issue because currently GOLD does not support "INSERT BEFORE" in linker scripts, and looks like there is no plan to implement support for it (details [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15373)).

The error from gold looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: myscript.ld:20:12: syntax error, unexpected STRING
/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: unable to parse script file myscript.ld
```

The script looks like this:

```
 SECTIONS{
        /DISCARD/ :{*(.IP*INFO)}
        .data1          :
        {
             data_section_start = LOADADDR(.data);
             bss_section_start = LOADADDR(.bss);
             rodata_section_start = LOADADDR(.rodata);

             PROVIDE_HIDDEN(mybin_start = .);
             *(.MyBinSegment)
             PROVIDE_HIDDEN(mybin_end = .);
        }
        .mysec1          :
        {
             PROVIDE_HIDDEN(mysec1_start = .);
             *(.mysec1)
             PROVIDE_HIDDEN(mysec1_end = .);
        }
     }
     INSERT BEFORE .data
```

I was wondering whether there is a better way to write this script to avoid using `INSERT BEFORE .data;`.

Thanks.

Simone